# Call any one of a number of functions until we get a specified result

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

I've got this ugly bit of code that looks a bit like this ...

```
TestResult GetFirstTestResult()
{
    var result = TestMethod1();
    if(result is EmptyResult)
    {
        result = TestMethod2();
    }

    if(result is EmptyResult)
    {
        result = TestMethod3();
    }

    // ...

    if(result is EmptyResult)
    {
        result = TestMethodN();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Basically, I need to run a number of tests until I find one that has some values.

Now whilst the above code isn't pretty, for a small(ish) value of `N` is is managable. Sadly, in my case, `N` could get fairly big.

Is there a way of writing this using a loop, something along the lines of this pseudo code...

```
TestResult GetFirstTestResult()
{
    TestResult[] results = {TestMethod1(), TestMethod2(), TestMethod3(), .. TestMethodN()};
    return results.First(test=>!test.Result is Emptyresult);
}
```

such that each of the test methods were invoked *in the loop* so only the minimum number of them were actually executed?

**EDIT**
With thanks to [Ric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/885626/ric) and [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622391/simon-m%E1%B6%9Ckenzie) I've got this...

```
TestResult GetFirstTestResult()
{
    return new Func<TestResult>[]
        {
            TestMethod1,
            TestMethod2,
            TestMethodN
        }.Select(t => t())
                      .FirstOrDefault(r => !(r is EmptyResult)) ?? new EmptyResult();
}
```

which calls each method in turn until it finds one where the result is not of type `EmptyResult` and returns that. If no such result is found it returns `new EmptyResult()`

Comment: Why not just a simple loop with `break`/`return` logic?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How are you suggesting arranging the method calls in to a loop?

Comment: I actually prefer your LINQ-based solution, along with [@Ric's late-evaluated enhancement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35317628/622391), e.g. `new Func<TestResult>[] {TestMethod1, /*etc*/}.Select(x => x()).First(x => x != EmptyResult)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this? Obviously I don't have all your code so cannot verify the correctness, but you should be able to modify as you require:

```
List<Func<TestResult>> methods = new List<Func<TestResult>>() { TestMethod1, TestMethod2, TestMethod3 };

foreach(var f in methods)
{
    if(f().Result != EmptyResult)
    {
        break; //or something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a Muppet! Why didn't I see that?

Comment: If i stare at something too long i can't see the wood from the trees!

Comment: Is there a special reason for using a `List<>` over an array? `new Func<TestResult>[] {...}` is less verbose, and would offer the same functionality...

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie not really - first thing that came to mind, an array would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using delegates:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Func<int>> tests = new List<Func<int>>() { T1, T2, T3 };
        Func<int> test = tests.First(t => t() != 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Test is " + test.Method.Name);
    }

    static int T1() { return 0; }
    static int T2() { return 1; }
    static int T3() { return 1; }
}
```